# Online repository for double blind submissions

Tags: publications, online-publication

Some conferences in my area require double-blind submissions. I'm a junior faculty member and I would like to put a timestamp on my results by publishing them online, as there is a nonzero probability that someone else might come up with a similar result soon.

The problem is that none of the existing online repositories for publishing research papers that I'm aware of ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/), [EEE](http://www.eccc.uni-trier.de/)) don't have an option for (temporarily) hiding the authors of an uploaded manuscript.

> Is there any repository that I'm not aware that would allow me to do this. Or is there any other way to get a public timestamp on my results while still being able to submit to double-blind venues?

Comment: Please read [How can I timestamp my paper without violating double-blind review?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/31018/546)

Comment: The current version of this question is pretty much a shopping question which is not allowed on our site. However, the question I linked in the comment above might answer your worry. I'll leave this to the community/mods as whether to close this one..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I timestamp my paper without violating double-blind review?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/31018/how-can-i-timestamp-my-paper-without-violating-double-blind-review)

Answer (score 1):

I think the premise in double blind reviewing is that the reviewers will not try to discover the author's identity. Searching for it is implicitly (perhaps explicitly) discouraged. So an honorable double blind reviewer would not see a signed time stamped preprint on, say, arXiv. Some journals with a double blind policy clearly allow that.